# LG-G3 Smart Keyboard?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, keyboard, lg, lg-g3

On the LG-G3, we can easily adjust the portrait keyboard like so:

[image]

But, despite looking for many hours for some sort of setting, I can't seem to find a way to increase the size of the landscape keyboard mode, which is clearly too small:

[image]

Is there anyway to change the height of that keyboard?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Comment: If you don't mind changing the keyboard, you can use [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey). You can adjust the size of the keyboard in that app.

Comment: @Firelord I would prefer using the lg g3 keyboard. Is it possible?